# Is prototype javascript library able to handle AJAX requests through HTTPS?

Tags: ajax, security, https, prototypejs

*CONTEXT:*

I'm currently developing a website that will involve Credit Card numbers handling. Confidential data are now sent through an AJAX request using the prototype library. I'm using simple HTTP request for now, as I'm developing, but later on I would like everything to run on HTTPS.

*QUESTION:*

- Can prototype perform HTTPS AJAX request ?
- If it is not default, how can I force it ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the SSL makes any difference here. Just make sure your url for request has https.

I use jQuery without any problems over http & https.